# Email Verification Throwing Error If The User Isnt Signed In Before Clicking The Verify Email Link

Tags: django, django-allauth

Im using allauth with email confirmation. If I register a new user, then log in (without being verified), then open the email and follow the link, the user gets successfully verified in the db and can continue using the site.

However, if I register a new user, then log them out, then open the email and follow the link, the user gets successfully verified in the db, but the link throws this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/confirm-email/MzA:1jZWYM:JgeeuPYRC3QnGOPs3L7kzZEFi5M/
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

So basically, the user has to already be logged in when they click the link in the email for it to work without error, but if they are not logged in and follow the verify link in the email, they get verified in the db but an error is thrown.

PS- this is using normal registration (nothing to do with social accounts).I should also mention that i did copy the email view from the allauth git and put it in my code, but later deleted it (id expect after deleting it it would look in the default place)

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 301, in post
    return redirect(redirect_url)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 41, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 131, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', include('about.urls')),
    path('contact_us/', include('contact_us.urls')),
    path('enrolment/', include('enrolment.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('profile/', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('our_services/', include('our_services.urls')),
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like django-allauth looks for a different 'login' view than you have? 

if you can share where the error is thrown it would be easier to help you

Comment: I did copy the email view from the allauth git and put it in my code, but later deleted it (id expect after deleting it it would look in the default place?). I'm really not sure where in my code the error is being thrown from, should I paste the traceback?

Comment: yes please and also your 'urls.py' might help

Comment: I added them. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the following line in the traceback:

`File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 301, in post`

it leads to [this line](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/701756f48fc627ed1f9cef77e6ad887c2e95e0f8/allauth/account/app_settings.py#L66) in django-allauth:

`self._setting("EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL",settings.LOGIN_URL)`

I guess you have neither the `LOGIN_URL` nor a `EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL` set in your `settings.py`?

Or it can't be found?

Comment: Thank you so much. Im new to programming but will try to go through my traceback more closely. I appreciate the help